# BIRT displaying options: dynamically reorder the sequence of items

Tags: javascript, eclipse, report, birt, report-designer

I'm using BIRT report designer v4.8 and trying to rearrange the sequence of items when displaying (or generating) the report based on users' preferences.

Suppose we created a report that has three sections, where each section is a Grid with a Table inside it.
[image]

When running the report, different users may like the sections in the report come out in different sequence.

- For example, user1 may want it to be displayed as Section1, Section2, Section3
  [image]
- user2 may want it to be displayed as Section2, Section1, Section3
  [image]
- user3 may want it to be displayed as Section3, Section2, Section1
  [image]
- etc.

Can we achieve this by creating parameters and linking them to the Element ID and, then using some scripts to reorder the display/render sequence dynamically? Or are there any other methods to achieve this functionality?